# what does "nice and -adjective" mean?

Tags: meaning

> In order to hit the ball higher, you can play it just a little farther forward in your stance. Try to set your wrists a little sooner on your backswing. Make sure you allow your wrists to reset all the way in your followthrough and **keep it nice and high**.

In the above sentence, how does it differ from just saying *keep it high*?

Comment: This meaning is found in dictionaries; in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/nice), for instance, it is sense 2, " used before adjectives or adverbs to emphasize how pleasant something is".

Comment: 'nice' means "the way it should usually and properly be done"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. The "nice and" just says that the thing (in this case, that the bat stays high during the follow through) is a good, pleasing, comfortable thing. In every usage I can think of, the words 'nice and" can just be mentally deleted without changing the meaning of the line.

(EDITED upon recommendation of StoneyB)

Comment: Not merely 'good', I think, but 'comfortable' or 'pleasing'. According to COCA, the ten most common adjectives with *nice and* are easy, warm, clean, quiet, sweet, hot, soft, soft, cool, smooth, neat, fresh.

Comment: Yep, it's a subtle thing, but those words do work better.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd sentences contradict each other - as you say, "nice and" does convey _some_ meaning.